# Node NPM proxy authentication - how do I configure it?

Tags: node.js, proxy, npm, http-proxy

I'm new to Node and trying to install TypeScript using the following command:

```
npm install -g typescript
```

I get the following error:

```
if you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the 'proxy' config is set properly.
```

I have set my proxy using the following commands:

```
npm config set proxy http://Username:Pa55w0rd@proxyhostname
npm config set https-proxy http://Username:Pa55w0rd@proxyhostname
```

and tried this also:

```
npm config set proxy http://"ninjadev:5trongP@ssw0rd"@proxy.some-bigcorp.com
npm config set https-proxy http://"ninjadev:5trongP@ssw0rd"@proxy.some-bigcorp.com
```

But none of them work. I am working behind a copmpany proxy with authentication, so I think this is stopping me from connecting. I have added my username and password and this also didn't work.

Does anyone have any idea how I can connect to npm whilst using the company proxy and authentication?

Thanks

Comment: use this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48224025/npm-behind-a-proxy-with-the-character-in-my-password/50214574#50214574).
it worked for me.

Comment: Be sure to URL encode `@` in passwords as `%40`. Otherwise it will probably think `ninjadev:5trongP` is the user/pass and `ssw0rd"@proxy.some-bigcorp.com` (or something similar) will be the host.

Answer (score 39):

Did you try with

```
npm config set proxy http://"ninjadev:5trongP@ssw0rd"@proxy.some-bigcorp.com:PORT
npm config set https-proxy http://"ninjadev:5trongP@ssw0rd"@proxy.some-bigcorp.com:PORT
```

where PORT can be 8080 if you don't have the proxy port?

Comment: Note that password containing **@** cannot be parsed.

Comment: @FaizanMubasher for passwords with an `@` or other meaningful special characters, replace them by their `encodeURIComponent` versions. For example, `@` becomes `%40`.

Answer (score 15):

This worked for me:

```
npm config set https-proxy "ninjadev:5trongP@ssw0rd"@proxy.some-bigcorp.com:PORT
```

Whithout `http/https` before.

Comment: worked for me too, should be marked as the answer, nicedone @Supersharp

Answer (score 3):

The following code worked for me:

`npm config set proxy "http://"username:password"@proxy.big-corp.com"`

Answer (score 1):

This thing worked for me:

`npm config set proxy http://"ninjadev:5trongP@ssw0rd"@proxy.some-bigcorp.com:PORT`

Open `cmd` as an administrator and past the command there.  Modify the command with credentials provided for your user.

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu-18.04 make sure that in home directory `.npmrc` file contains:

```
proxy=http://username:password@proxyhostname:port

https-proxy=http://username:password@proxyhostname:port
```

Comment: From Review: Hi, this post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer and improve it, or just post it as a comment.