# NPM behind a proxy with the character "@" in my password

Tags: node.js, npm, proxy

I am trying to set NPM (v9.4.0) proxy but I am facing the following error when running `npm i -g npm@latest`:

```
npm ERR! code E407
npm ERR! 407 Proxy Authentication Required: npm@latest
```

The password I use for the proxy contains an "@" character an I suspect this is the root cause of the issue. I tried with a "\" before the "@" and also

```
npm config set proxy http://"user:MyP@ssword"@proxy.big.corp.fr:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://"user:MyP@ssword"@proxy.big.corp.fr:8080
```

but without success. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: I don't think you need the double quotes `"`

Comment: Shall I use the "\" before the "@" character?

Comment: Try: `user:MyP@ssword@proxy.big.corp.fr:8080`

Comment: I already tried, checking 10 times the password, without success.

Comment: Oh, password with `@` sign can not be parsed correctly

Comment: ahh... Then I will try to change my password :-). I'll let you know.

Comment: Do you know if it is the case for al special characters?

Comment: It applies for all URL reserved characters. You can try url-encode the password, but I am not sure if it works. http://blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm

Comment: Thank you for your help Khang

Answer (score 11):

After many research about this problem and test more than 10 solutions like set with this commands:

npm config set proxy "http://domain%5Cusername:password@servername:port/"

but not worked for me.
then test [CNTLM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18569054/npm-behind-ntlm-proxy/18570201#18570201) but CNTLM didn't work for me. I tried all possible combinations. NPM was giving Authentication error.
finally i test Fiddler and saved my time. It is easy to install and configure. Open Fiddler => Rule => Automatically Authenticated.

Open C:\Users\your username\.npmrc file and use this configurations

registry=http://registry.npmjs.org

proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8888

https-proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8888

http-proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8888

strict-ssl=true

remove npm folder in this path C:\Users\your username\AppData\Roaming.
Using following command:

```
npm install express
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean --force
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Comment: Tried everything, but only this worked. Really important is the 'Automatically Authenticated' check. Thanks!

Comment: Where it is 'Automatically Authenticated' located

Comment: It is in the answer.  "Open FIDDLER => Rule => Automatically Authenticated."

Answer (score 4):

You can also convert your password to BASE64 encode

```
npm config set proxy http://<user>:<base64 password>@proxy.big.corp.fr:8080
```

Sample:

```
npm config set proxy http://myuser:bXlwYXNzd29yZA==@proxy.big.corp.fr:8080
```

To convert use site https://www.base64encode.org/

Comment: this is a nice solution

Answer (score 0):

I checked and found, in my company, an anonymous proxy exists. This also solved my problem.